# How to split at a particular word in list using python

Tags: python, list

Here is my list,

```
['Query Date                                :September 07, 2017',
 'Address                                    :Aguila arizona',
 'Latitude                                :33.9428069', 'Longitude                                :-113.1740805',
 'Elevation                                :2170.4 Feet',
 'Elevation Limitation:  ASCE 7* Ground Snow **LoadElevation** 3,000 feet: Ground Snow Load is0 ',
 'Elevation > 3,000 and 4,500 feet: Ground Snow Load is5 ',
 'Elevation > 4,500 and 5,400 feet: Ground Snow Load is10 ',
 '']
```

I want to split on a particular word(ie LoadElevation) which is at 5th element in the list. So after Load it should get splitted.

**Output should be like**

```
['Query Date                                :September 07, 2017',
 'Address                                    :Aguila arizona', 'Latitude                                :33.9428069',
 'Longitude                                :-113.1740805', 'Elevation                                :2170.4 Feet',
 'Elevation Limitation:  ASCE 7* Ground Snow **Load',
 'Elevation** 3,000 feet: Ground Snow Load is0 ', 
 'Elevation > 3,000 and 4,500 feet: Ground Snow Load is5 ',
 'Elevation > 4,500 and 5,400 feet: Ground Snow Load is10 ', 
 '']
```

Guys help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't see `LoadElevation` anywhere... are my eyes playing tricks on my or is your question unclear?

Comment: Please construct a readable example, we don't need to see your convoluted actual adata.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ please see the bold one which i marked

Comment: Could you replace those lists with shorter ones that actually fit on a normal computer screen? It's needlessly difficult to find the difference between input and output if you have to scroll 400 characters to the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short solution using `re.findall()` function:

```
import re
l = ['Query Date                                :September 07, 2017', 'Address                                    :Aguila arizona', 'Latitude                                :33.9428069', 'Longitude                                :-113.1740805', 'Elevation                                :2170.4 Feet', 'Elevation Limitation:  ASCE 7* Ground Snow LoadElevation 3,000 feet: Ground Snow Load is0 ', 'Elevation > 3,000 and 4,500 feet: Ground Snow Load is5 ', 'Elevation > 4,500 and 5,400 feet: Ground Snow Load is10 ', '']
l[5:6] = re.findall(r'.*\Load|Elevation.*', l[5])

print(l)
```

The output:

```
['Query Date                                :September 07, 2017', 'Address                                    :Aguila arizona', 'Latitude                                :33.9428069', 'Longitude                                :-113.1740805', 'Elevation                                :2170.4 Feet', 'Elevation Limitation:  ASCE 7* Ground Snow Load', 'Elevation 3,000 feet: Ground Snow Load is0 ', 'Elevation > 3,000 and 4,500 feet: Ground Snow Load is5 ', 'Elevation > 4,500 and 5,400 feet: Ground Snow Load is10 ', '']
```

Comment: ['Query Date                                :September 07, 2017', 'Address                                    :Aguila arizona', 'Latitude                                :33.9428069', 'Longitude                                :-113.1740805', 'Elevation                                :2170.4 Feet', 'Elevation > 3,000 and 4,500 feet: Ground Snow Load is5 ', 'Elevation > 4,500 and 5,400 feet: Ground Snow Load is10 ', '']
its not working when i try with this as input. please help me

Comment: @ppriyanka, but your new input doesn't contain split keyword `**LoadElevation**`. It's evident.  what do you mean?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest ** is because She has done bold you might need to remove it from re pattern..

Comment: @ppriyanka, is that true what Nirmi said?

Comment: Basically based on Elevation feet it should compare with Elevation Limtation and take the respective Content Finally the output should look like ['01/09/17', ' Aguila,Arizona', '33.9428069', '-113.1740805', '21704', ' ASCE 7* Ground Snow Load', '0']. Can someone help with this also

Comment: @ppriyanka, now, you are showing another input example. What is the split rule for it?

Comment: There is no split rule. Here u have to compare and then take the appropriate value for it.

Comment: @ppriyanka, what does mean *Elevation **Limitation*** ?

Answer (score 0):

Asumming your "splitting element" occurs only once, get its index, slice up to that index, insert whatever you want, then add the rest of the list.

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 'SplitHere', 3, 4]
>>> idx = a.index('SplitHere')
>>> a[:idx] + ['Split', 'Here'] + a[idx+1:]
[1, 2, 'Split', 'Here', 3, 4]
```

I hardcoded the split because you did not give any rules or criteria by which to split the target word.

Comment: You could also modify the list in-place: `a[idx:idx+1] = ['Split', 'Here']`

Answer (score 0):

For generic you can try followinig code:

```
import re
for index,line in enumerate(list1):
     if("LoadElevation" in line):
             newList = re.split("LoadElevation",line)
             new_index = index
             list1 = list1[:index]+ [ele + "Load" if index1%2==0 else "Elevation"+ele for index1,ele in enumerate(newList)] + list1[index+1:]

print list1 #['Query Date                                :September 07, 2017', 'Address                                    :Aguila arizona', 'Latitude                                :33.9428069', 'Longitude                                :-113.1740805', 'Elevation                                :2170.4 Feet', 'Elevation Limitation:  ASCE 7* Ground Snow **Load', 'Elevation** 3,000 feet: Ground Snow Load is0 ', 'Elevation > 3,000 and 4,500 feet: Ground Snow Load is5 ', 'Elevation > 4,500 and 5,400 feet: Ground Snow Load is10 ', '']
```

Comment: Basically based on Elevation feet it should compare with Elevation Limtation and take the respective Content

Finally the output should look like

['01/09/17', ' Aguila,Arizona', '33.9428069', '-113.1740805', '21704', ' ASCE 7* Ground Snow Load', '0']. Can someone help with this also

Comment: You might need to add new question for same as per your new comment now final output is changed.

Comment: ya, but please try to help here.

Comment: from your output from where 0 came? last element of list?

Comment: print [ele.split(':')[1]  for ele in list1 if ':' in ele]
 you can try this I will work partial as I am not getting condition with which your last two data came..

Comment: ,['Query Date                                :September 07, 2017', 'Address                                    :Aguila arizona', 'Latitude                                :33.9428069', 'Longitude                                :-113.1740805', 'Elevation                                :2170.4 Feet', 'Elevation Limitation:  ASCE 7* Ground Snow Load', 'Elevation 3,000 feet: Ground Snow Load is0 '] Ground Snow Load is0 because elevation feet falls between the range. Also refer the question you will also get to know